# Pine-script How to hide previous plots

Tags: pine-script

How do I hide previous plots? The code below is a simple 20/50 ema crossover strategy. It plots blue crosses over candles whenever I'm in a long trade. How do I keep the blue crosses over the candles for the most recent trade and hide the previous ones?

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

ATR = atr(14)

longCondition = crossover(ema(close, 20), ema(close, 50))

float longEntry = na
float longSL = na
float longTP = na

longEntry := longCondition ? close : longEntry[1]
longSL := longCondition ? close - ATR*2 : longSL[1]
longTP := longCondition ? close + ATR*4 : longTP[1]

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("tp or sl", "long", stop=longSL, limit=longTP) 

plot(ema(close,20))
plot(ema(close,50), color=color.white)

imLong = strategy.position_size > 0
plotshape(imLong)
```

[Please see the attached image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAOwi.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this ok?

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

ATR = atr(14)

longCondition = crossover(ema(close, 20), ema(close, 50))

float longEntry = na
float longSL = na
float longTP = na

longEntry := longCondition ? close : longEntry[1]
longSL := longCondition ? close - ATR*2 : longSL[1]
longTP := longCondition ? close + ATR*4 : longTP[1]

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("tp or sl", "long", stop=longSL, limit=longTP) 


plot(ema(close,20))
plot(ema(close,50), color=color.white)

imLong = strategy.position_size > 0

is_today = year == year(timenow) and month == month(timenow) and dayofmonth == dayofmonth(timenow)
Lastshape = input(false, title = "Enable Last Shape") // Enable or Disable all plots for TP and SL except last ones 
plotshape(imLong and (is_today or Lastshape == false))
```

Comment: I see, you used time and date as filter, very clever. Thank you, I will be using the concept!

Answer (score 0):

- use label([refrence](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#examples-of-classic-indicators) ) instead of ploatshape
- use label.delete to delete previous drawing

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I used plotshape() just as an example. I actually want to hide plot() and fill() which both can't be deleted.